# Getting to work kinect v2 as microphone in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, audio, kinect, openkinect

I'm using Kinect v2 in Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to get a way to use it as a microphone using C++ as the programming language. I already have an application in C++ and Qt where the application redirects the audio streams from different audio input devices to some audio output devices.

In that application, it is possible to get a list of available audio input devices for that PC. Currently, the application already lists **Xbox NUI Sensor Analog 4-channel Input** as one of the audio input devices, as does **ubuntu sound settings application**.  I have also checked if the Kinect Input audio device supports audio format of 44100 Hz sampling rate, sampling size of 16 bit, audio/pcm codec and 2 channel counts and apparently it does support.

The problem is that, in my application, I cannot hear any sound on the output when I use kinect xbox as the microphone, whereas in case of other audio input devices I can hear the sound just fine. I'm not sure what the solution could be.

I didn't find much about the microphone in **libfreenect2** pages either. I know that libfreenect2 lists **"audio transfer"** as one of it's missing features, but on the other hand in the documentation it is also written in the **Issues and Future Work** section.

```
Audio. There is basic access to Kinect v2's audio via ALSA (Linux). However, this is directional audio with intricate calibration, which is probably beyond the scope of this image processing library.
```

Does this mean that it's still possible to get access to the audio stream from Kinect V2 microphone via ALSA in ubuntu 14.04 or only the fact, at most, that the Ubunut system can only detect Kinect v2 as an audio input device but cannot be used for actual recording purposes?

If it is the first case, could you suggest me how I can get an access to the audio stream of the Kinect microphone(I cannot find anything regarding the audio or the microphone in any of the docs of libfreenect2)? Do you have any other way to get kinect v2 microphone running apart from using libfreenect2?